# Elasticsearch jdbc river eats up entire memory

Tags: jdbc, lucene, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am trying to index 16 million docs(47gb) from a mysql table into elasticsearch index. I am using [jparante's elasticsearch jdbc river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) to do this. But, after creating the river and waiting for about 15 mins, the entire heap memory gets consumed without any sign of the river running or docs getting indexed. The river used to run fine when I had around 10-12 million records to index. I have tried running the river 3-4 times, but in vain.

`Heap Memory pre allocated to the ES process = 10g`

elasticsearch.yml

```
 cluster.name: test_cluster

 index.cache.field.type: soft
 index.cache.field.max_size: 50000
 index.cache.field.expire: 2h

 cloud.aws.access_key: BBNYJC25Dij8JO7YM23I(fake)
 cloud.aws.secret_key: GqE6y009ZnkO/+D1KKzd6M5Mrl9/tIN2zc/acEzY(fake)
 cloud.aws.region: us-west-1

 discovery.type: ec2
 discovery.ec2.groups: sg-s3s3c2fc(fake)
 discovery.ec2.any_group: false
 discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3m

 gateway.recover_after_nodes: 1
 gateway.recover_after_time: 1m

 bootstrap.mlockall: true

 network.host: 10.111.222.33(fake)
```

river.sh

```
curl -XPUT 'http://--address--:9200/_river/myriver/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://--address--:3306/mydatabase",
        "user" : "USER",
        "password" : "PASSWORD",
        "sql" : "select * from mytable order by creation_time desc",
        "poll" : "5d",
        "versioning" : false
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "myindex",
        "type" : "mytype",
        "bulk_size" : 500,
        "bulk_timeout" : "240s"
    }
}'
```

System properties:

```
16gb RAM
200gb disk space
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of elasticsearch-river-jdbc (find out with `ls -lrt plugins/river-jdbc/`) this bug might be closed (https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/issues/45)

Otherwise file a bug report on Github.